# How would you create a thumbnail of the first page of a pdf using php but not using ghostwrite and imagemagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

How would you create a thumbnail of the first page of a pdf using php but not using ghostwrite and imagemagick.  I have restrictions on a clients server as the provider will not allow anything to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Two options spring to mind:

POST the pdf to a script running on another server which does have a PDF reading library, do the processing there, and return the image in the response.

Another idea is to upload a statically-compiled copy of ghostscript and upload that to the webhost and call that using system(). While the host might not install and support software for you, a statically compiled binary has worked for me in these situations.

Comment: Thanks for your response, where would you be able to download a static version of ghostscript?